# Jaalee beacon with altbeacon?

Tags: altbeacon

I have been trying to connect to a Jaalee beacon using [`altbeacon library`](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)  without success. 
The service UUID is 0x00001532-1212-EFDE-1523-785FEABCD123
What is the correct setting for setBeaconLayout in altbeacon?
For example for another type of beacons that is

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```

I have searched everywhere and I cannot find it. Thanks

** UPDATE **
I have checked using a program scanning for bluetooth devices and indeed it is a Jaalee device. 
The bluetooth device has name "jaalee"; ScanRecord is

```
[mAdvertiseFlags=4, mServiceUuids=[0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=0, mDeviceName=jaalee]
```

Comment: well, at least I think it is a Jaalee beacon. I have bought it on Amazon and it may be a fake. It is recognised by Jaalee's eBeacon app but not by the Jaalee Demo code provided with the SDK

Comment: Can you detect it with the Beacon Locate app?  It is based on the same library. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate

Comment: No, I cannot detect it with the Beacon Locate app

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can detect the device transmitting a Bluetooth LE Service UUID, but cannot detect it with the Locate App means that:

- The Jalee device is not transmitting a standard AltBeacon or iBeacon frame, both of which are detected by the Locate app.
- The Jalee device is connectable, and might be configurable if you can find a Jalee configuration app.  This may allow you to configure it to transmit the standard bracon frames described above.